# How to call remote command in "multipart/form-data" form in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have uploadBean which is sessionScoped. I want to call the remote command  `myRemoteFunction` in oncomplete:

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(mdb)$/"        
            description="Select File"               
            dragDropSupport="true"
            multiple="false"
            fileLimit="1" 
            update="growl"
            widgetVar="fileUploadWidget"
            oncomplete="PF('fileUploadWidget').reset(); myRemoteFunction()"/>

    <p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteFunction" action="#{uploadBean.remoteFunction}"/>

<script>
 PrimeFaces.widget.FileUpload.prototype.reset = function() {   
        this.clearMessages();
        return this.init(this.cfg);
    }

 </script>
    </h:form>
```

In bean side:

```
public void remoteFunction(){       
        //some logic here after the file is uplodaded   
    }

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    //some growl messages are set here
    // and let the progress bar vanish immediately

}
```

When I set the remote command "myRemoteFunction" I got this error message:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

I don't want to call remoteFunction in handleFileUpload function. Because when I call it, the progress bar shows like the file is uploaded completely but it doesn't disappear until the process exits from hadleFileUpload function. Because the logic in the remoteFuction may take five seconds to fifteen seconds.

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see potentially two things that could be wrong with your code. First one, not necessarily wrong but, 
`PF('fileUploadWidget').reset();` I'm not aware that there is a reset function on the upload widget, but this could be registered by you, or some version that I'm not familiar with, but do check your code for javascript errors.

Second, surely wrong, you need to call the *myRemoteFunction* with the paranthesis `myRemoteFunction()` otherwise it will simply silently ignore.

Comment: I use reset function to reset the upload file limit( I reset the count to let user upload another file). And as I remove the unnecessary code block I forget the parenthesis of myRemoteFunction(). So, this is the nearly original code block. Please check it again.